# jqueryUI control group child selector overflow

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am trying to figure out how to enable vertical overflow for a jqueryui controlgroup selectmenu.  The content is dynamic, so there are container drops and refreshes in play.  Everything works, but I cannot get the css to work on a selectmenu when it's part of a controlgroup.  (Standalone selectmenu works fine)

html div holder:

```
    <div id="info1" class="info1" style="font-size:.9em;">
```

code:

```
   $('#info1').empty();
        $('<button id="infofirst" name="infofirst" data-icon="ui-icon-seek-first">First</button><button id="infoprevious" name="infoprevious">Previous</button>').appendTo('#info1');
        while(countera-1 < sp){
        $('<label for="infolist'+countera+'">'+countera+'</label><input type="radio" name="infolist" id="infolist'+countera+'" value='+countera+'>'
        ).appendTo('#info1');
        countera++;}
        $('<select id="listmoreinfo1" name="listmoreinfo1"><option disabled selected>More info... ('+tp+' Total)</option>').appendTo( '#info1' );
        var counter = 1;
        while(tp+1 > counter){
            $('<option value="'+counter+'">Entry '+counter+' of '+tp+'</option>').appendTo( '#listmoreinfo1' );
            counter++;
        }
        $('<button id="infonext" name="infonext">Next</button><button id="infolast" name="infolast">Last</button>').appendTo( '#info1' );
        $( ".info1" ).controlgroup();
        $( ".info1" ).controlgroup("refresh");
        $(".listmoreinfo1")
            .selectmenu({
                classes:{
                    "overflow2"
                }
            });
        $('#infolist'+p).prop('checked', true);
        $( ".info1" ).controlgroup("refresh");
```

and style

```
    .overflow2 {
height:200px;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

}

I'm thinking there has to be a simple solution that I am just missing.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found a solution on my own....

```
.ui-autocomplete{overflow-y:scroll;height:200px;overflow-x:hidden;}
```

This is the only way I found to be able to handle the overflow of the dropdown list.